# WordPress Related Posts thumbnails work but permalink error

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, thumbnails

I am attempting to show 4 related posts beneath each WP post. The thumbnails work correctly, pulling in the feature image and the title, but the permalink does not. It comes in as "http://example.com/original-post-name/< ? the_permalink(); ? >/" (spaces added) and is clickable but of course no content found. This exact code works fine on a different site of mine, but not this new one. I'm sure it could be improved - I'm fairly new to wordpress theming.

```
 <?php
 // Default arguments
  $args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => 4,
 'post__not_in'   => array( get_the_ID() ),
 'no_found_rows'  => true,
 );

$cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' ); 
$cats_ids = array();  
foreach( $cats as $wpex_related_cat ) {
$cats_ids[] = $wpex_related_cat->term_id; 
}
if ( ! empty( $cats_ids ) ) {
$args['category__in'] = $cats_ids;
}

// Query posts
$wpex_query = new wp_query( $args );

// Loop through posts
foreach( $wpex_query->posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<!--<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 
'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>-->
<div class="relatedthumb">
<a rel="external" href="<?the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?><br 
/>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
</div>

<?php
// End loop
endforeach;

// Reset post data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Apologies if this has been asked before - I've tried searching and hoping this is a simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong opening tag for php

```
<a rel="external" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

So it's a typo